# DEPENDENCE AND CORRELATION. biostatistic italian test

Tags: correlation, independence

In the test there are these 2 questions. My friends and i cannot tell the correct answer because it is so confusing. It is a multiple choice test.

Are two dependent variables correlated?

- A. always
- B. never
- C. only if r>0
- D. yes if referred to the same feature then the same question but with independent

I  hope you can help me it is driving me crazy

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: Also, this is only one question.

Comment: Gabriele option D does not make much sense to me. Has something got lost in translation? But as already stated you will get better answers if you tell us about your thoughts.

Comment: I wonder if something has been lost in the translation from Italian. In the English, however, I do not see a correct answer, because the answer is that dependent variables do not have to be correlated but can be, and that correlation can be less than zero (strong negative correlation is still dependence).

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if something has been lost in the translation from Italian. In the translation, however, I do not see a correct answer, because the answer is that dependent variables do not have to be correlated but can be, and that correlation can be less than zero (strong negative correlation is still dependence).

For an example of dependent variables that are uncorrelated, consider points along the edge of a circle or that form an $X$ shape. A few other examples are given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595716/247274), my favorite of which is the [dinosaur](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/595761/247274).